# How to distinguish "timesheets pending for approval" & "timesheets awaiting for your approval" in phrases?

Tags: phrase-requests

There are two buttons. 
Button A is for the timesheets submitted by user but still waiting for someone's approval, I want button A displays like this: **Pending Approval (3)**

Note: (3) means the quantity of timesheets that pending for approval.

And button B is for the timesheets submitted by others but require for this user's approval.

My question: How to describe Button B? Should I make it as "Awaiting for your  approval", or any shorter pharse?

Comment: The actual distinction here is "Your timesheets"  & "Others' timesheets" (both pending approval though in different directions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these buttons seem to be somewhat in note form, "pending approval" is appropriate.  However, "awaiting for your approval" is repetitive, as "awaiting" means "wait for", meaning that you have used "for" twice.  Just omit the "for", resulting in "awaiting your approval", and you're done.  :)